# Create column with corresponding values from another dataframe using pandas.DataFrame.merge

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, merge

EDIT: I have changed data1.code1 to have a duplicate value ... the original post did not have a duplicate value

I would like to create a column in a df using pandas.DataFrame.merge .
I want df2 to have a column 'name2' that corresponds to df1.name1 .
For example, 103 corresponds with E in df1, so I want the df2.name2 to have E next to the two 103's.

```
data1 = {'code1':[101, 101, 103, 104, 105, 106], 
        'name1':['A', 'A', 'E', 'B', 'B', 'C']}
  
# Create DataFrame 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

print(df1)


data2 = {'code2':[101, 101, 102, 103, 103, 106]}
  
# Create DataFrame 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

print(df2)


data3 = {'code3':[101, 102, 102, 103, 103, 106], 
         'name3':['A', 'A', 'A', 'E', 'E', 'C']}

what_i_want_df2_to_be = pd.DataFrame(data3)

print(what_i_want_df2_to_be)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
df2['name3'] = df2.code2.map(df1.set_index('code1')['name1'])
df2
Out[411]: 
   code2 name3
0    101     A
1    102     A
2    102     A
3    103     E
4    103     E
5    106     C
```

Comment: the code you provided worked on my original question, but I did not do a good job of asking because it didn't work on my actual data. my actual data set has duplicate index values so the code did not work. I have adjusted the question so that data1.code1 has duplicates.